# Codeigniter folder structure for responsive website using hmvc extension

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, directory-structure, codeigniter-hmvc

I am creating responsive website using CodeIgniter with following roles

1. doctor
2. hospital
3. guest

Each role has admin dashboard.

The website has 3 versions.

1. desktop version
2. mobile versioin
3. tab version

I have decided to use the HMVC modular framework to group the modules in the project.

Can anybody suggest me the suitable folder structure to my requirement.

Thanks in advance,
Santosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@santosh,

You can use the HMVC folder structure for this problem

here you have to make a module for each

like if you want to make doctor module then make all the files and folders under doctor module

```
 Doctor
 -Controllers
  -controller_file.php
 -Models
  -model_file.php
 -View
  -view_file.php
```

and put them in your module folder.

And you can also use Bonfire version for the HMVC codeigniter.

please visit [cibonfire.com](http://cibonfire.com/)

this is the best for HMVC codeigniter